# rotate pod logs on kubernetes by time

Tags: kubernetes, logrotate

My team has a special requirement to delete all pod logs every X hours. This is cause the logs contain some sensitive info - we read and process them with fluentbit, but it's an issue that the logs are still there after.
I couldn't find any normal way to rotate them by time, only recommendations on the docker daemon logging driver that rotates by file size.
Is it possible to create a k8s cronjob to do something like "echo ''> /path/to/logfile" per pod/container? If yes, how?

I'd appreciate any help here.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Docker as your container runtime?

Comment: Yes. and as I said, didn't see an option to trigger a rotation on request or time it

Answer (score 8):

Kubernetes doesn’t provide built-in log rotation, but this functionality is available in many tools.

According to [Kubernetes Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/):

> An important consideration in node-level logging is implementing log
> rotation, so that logs don't consume all available storage on the
> node. Kubernetes is not responsible for rotating logs, but rather a
> deployment tool should set up a solution to address that. For example,
> in Kubernetes clusters, deployed by the kube-up.sh script, there is a
> [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) tool configured to run each hour. You can also set up a
> container runtime to rotate an application's logs automatically.

Below are some examples of how the log rotation can be implemented:

- [Enable Log Rotation in Kubernetes Cluster](https://vividcode.io/enable-log-rotation-in-kubernetes-cluster/)
- [logrotate-container](https://github.com/mkilchhofer/logrotate-container)

You can use them as a guide.

Answer (score 2):

Since kubernetes 1.21 you can configure the kubelet to rotate logs automatically. It is not done by time but by size, you may able to tune the size so fluentbit can pick the logs and after a short period kubelet rotates them.

If you configure rotation, the kubelet is responsible for rotating container logs and managing the logging directory structure. The kubelet sends this information to the container runtime (using CRI), and the runtime writes the container logs to the given location.

You can configure two kubelet configuration settings, containerLogMaxSize and containerLogMaxFiles, using the kubelet configuration file. These settings let you configure the maximum size for each log file and the maximum number of files allowed for each container respectively.

Full docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#log-rotation)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Wytrzymały Wiktor's answer. I have created a simple FastAPI web service that logs information in a log file. This log file will be rotated later using a scheduled K8s job. The deployment was tested on my local Minikube cluster.

I have a local persistent volume (PV) residing in the Minikube cluster and a persistent volume claim (PVC) that requests storage from this local PV. In my case, the deployment has one pod replica and pulls the docker image from the Minikube cluster. It mounts the `/var/log/fastapi_app` logging folder to the PVC. Then, the pod is exposed as service, listening on the 8000 port.

I am going to extract the important sections from the `deployment.yml` manifest file. For more detail, here is the [SzilvasiPeter/fastapi-kubernetes-minikube](https://github.com/SzilvasiPeter/fastapi-kubernetes-minikube/tree/main) GitHub repository.

First, we have to create a `ConfigMap` object that configures the log rotation behavior:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logrotate-config
data:
  my_logs.conf: |
    /var/log/fastapi_app/*.log {
      rotate 3
      size 100k
      compress
      delaycompress
      dateformat -%Y%m%d_%H%M%S
      missingok
      notifempty
      copytruncate
    }
```

The `/var/log/fastapi_app/*.log` path has to match with the mounted path. The log files are rotated 3 times before being removed and compressed if the size reaches 100 KiB. The `copytruncate` config is important because it can be used when some program cannot be told to close its log file and thus might *continue writing* (appending) to the previous log file forever. I experienced that if it is omitted, the web service can't write to the current log file after log rotation.

Next, the `CronJob` schedules the log rotation at every minute. Furthermore, we don't allow concurrent runs and we will also restart the pod on failure:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: app-logrotate
spec:
  # Execute the job at every minute
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: logrotate
            image: docker.io/kicm/logrotate
            volumeMounts:
            - name: local-storage
              mountPath: /var/log/fastapi_app
            - name: logrotate-conf
              mountPath: /etc/logrotate.d
          volumes:
            - name: local-storage
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: local-persistent-volume-claim
            - name: logrotate-conf
              configMap:
                name: logrotate-config
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

It pulls and uses the [docker.io/kicm/logrotate](https://hub.docker.com/r/kicm/logrotate) image to rotate the logs. Two paths are mounted to the cronjob: the logging folder, and the log rotation config. The logging folder path in the `CronJob` has to be the same as in the `Deployment` workload. The `logrotate` tool will consider the config files under the `/etc/logrotate.d` path. By adding the `my_logs.conf` under this mounted path, we can activate the log rotation on our log files.

Note that you can change the cronjob schedule with the help of the https://crontab.guru/ site. You can also visit the [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) documentation to fine-tune the configuration file.

References:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/